# setInterval() impeding on user-friendliness of UI, any fix?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm creating a chat using jQuery / PHP / JavaScript (please don't suggest node.js / redis / socket.io, I just want a solution to the issue presented).

The issue I am having with the below code is that because it refreshes every second (so it's a live-chat), it shows 100 messages, but when scrolling down, it snaps back up because it has refreshed.

Are there any good solutions to this issue?

Code:

```
var all_chats = setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: './requests/chat.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(chats) {
      $('.chat').html(chats);
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the entire contents of `.chat` every time there's an update?

Comment: You should append the content to the chat not replace

Answer (score 2):

```
var all_chats = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: './requests/chat.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (chats) {
            $('.chat').append(chats);
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```